# In the Graph API, which is the "permission to install custom tab"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our app installs apps (or "tabs") to our users' Facebook Business Pages. Our code has been running nicely for many years, but as is usually the case with Facebook, things break all the time. Because, well, Facebook.

Some of our recent installation attempts are now failing with an error message we've never seen before:

```
(#2069016) This page does not have permission to install custom tab
```

As far as Google is concerned, this Stack Overflow question will be the first instance of that particular error message on the internet... So, I don't know what to do.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

For reference the page access tokens we're using have the following scopes (verified just now):

```
user_friends, email, read_insights, publish_actions, manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, business_management, public_profile
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs has a note on top, _"The Page Tabs feature is only available to Pages with 2000 or more fans, or pages managed by whitelisted apps."_ - that's news to me as well; could you check whether that's the case for those pages?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs mentions the same thing, but adds an important bit of information: _"You can only create tabs on Pages that have 2000 or more fans, or if you are an app developer with Admin privileges on those Pages."_

Comment: Regarding permissions, nothing has changed AFAIK - `manage_pages` should be all you need to install the app on the page. So if the 2k+ fans requirement is fulfilled for the pages you are having problems with, I'd say file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Nearly all of the pages we work with have < 2k fans (we cater to small businesses). I'll do some testing on the pages we do publish to with 2k or more fans. The bit about being an ["app developer with Admin privileges"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs) is encouraging, at least. I'll do some experimentation in that regard, as well. Thanks for the links! :)

Comment: Ah, here we go, has been done already: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/406525746462249/ So yes, that error message is what you should get in case the page has less than 2k fans.

Comment: And here's the changelog entry, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11/#gapi-90-pages _"/page/tabs — Creating custom tabs with POST operations will only be available to Pages with 2000 or more fans, or pages managed by whitelisted apps. Existing custom tabs will be unaffected."_

Comment: (So many comments so quickly, decided to give this a proper answer ;-)

Comment: @CBroe: We are just started affecting this new revision, is there any other way to add the custom tab by the customers instead of using the post method.

Comment: @saifali both ways are already mentioned here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the change log, this is a 90 day breaking change, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11/#gapi-90-pages

> `/page/tabs` — Creating custom tabs with POST operations will only be available to Pages with 2000 or more fans, or pages managed by whitelisted apps. Existing custom tabs will be unaffected.

90 days in relation to the release of API v2.11, which was on November 7, 2017 - so you're starting to see the effects now.

This sounds as though the page tab add dialog was not affected (at least to me, I have not checked yet) - so presenting your app users with the dialog could allow them to easily install the app on their pages themselves, maybe give that a go. You can call it either via the JS SDK's FB.ui, or by redirecting the user to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID &redirect_uri=YOUR_URL`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs#adding

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe! For others who land here - I'm going to test our workflow with a user who is an admin of our app. Fingers crossed that it works!

Comment: Update: Performing the workflow as an app admin worked! This is a workable solution for us (at least in the short-term) since our app is used primarily in-house.

Comment: Facebook is changing always the rules and trying to get more money. New policy only lets install applications as tabs, through the graph api, if the page has more than 2000 fans. If that isn't the case, only authorized apps by Facebook can do it. I suppose this is a technique Facebook is using to get money from apps platforms (which need to install tabs by api) because the manual way (the link indicated in this answer) still works.

Comment: @CBroe : Is there any way to add custom tab , without 2k+  followers and not giving app permission ?

Comment: @Manikandan using the Page Tab Add Dialog, the page admin can add the app to the page themselves.

Comment: @CBroe I just attempted to use the Page Tab Add Dialog and admin got an error saying that their page does have have permission to add the tab.

Comment: Yep, also getting "This page does not have permission to install the custom tab." now. Any workarounds?

Comment: Following an active Facebook bug on the subsequent issue with the Page Tab Add Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1348060738673989/.

Comment: Anyone aware what a "fan" is? Is it a like, a follower or a combination of the 2?

Comment: @RckMrkr a fan is someone who has liked a page. Whether they actually follow it or not, does not matter. Pure following without liking is not being a fan.

Answer (score 2):

As CBroe suggests, installing a page tab using the redirect method still works.

Edit: sadly they've closed this loophole too

Comment: I hope this is true! This Facebook bug seems to indicate otherwise, unfortunately. Maybe something has changed in the last two months. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/205844513351283/

Answer (score 1):

The [Page Tabs reference page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs) states (emphasis added):

> You can only create tabs on Pages that have 2000 or more fans, or **if
>   you are an app developer with Admin privileges on those Pages.**

**So, if you're in the fortunate situation in which you personally have admin access to the page** (e.g. you created the page, the page owner granted you admin access, etc.), then you can still install apps even if it has fewer than 2000 fans.

I believe this exception is provided to enable developers to, well, develop apps (duh). However, this same ability allows us to install production apps to live pages.

---

Note: My experience with this workaround has been hit-and-miss. It always works for me, but it doesn't seem to work well for other devs at our company. I have a theory for why this seems to be the case. Experimentation suggests that there *may* be another requirement - it looks like *you might also need to have admin privileges on the actual app (Page Tab) you're attempting to install.*

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, even with this approach, we continued to encounter the aforementioned error when using the endpoint `/me/tabs/app_{$app_id}'`. For some inexplicable reason, using `/me/tabs` and providing the `app_id` in the `POST` data instead fixed the problem.

Comment: This is definitely becoming the weirdest API I have ever worked with. There is definitely something else to apply not explained in the documentation. I have followed all the steps and still not working. I am an admin of the application and of the page I am trying to connect.

Comment: Submit a bug! At least FB is pretty responsive to API bug reports nowadays

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I have detected that all the fanpages are blocked with less than 2000 followers I like that this is a problem or that sometimes it can and does not have less than that amount of followers